# ToggleButtons not updating with fillColor when pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to make a ToggleButtons column inside a StatefulWidget. When I press one of the buttons and print the current values of `isSelected`, it prints out the values correctly however the button in question does not seem to change according to its new `fillColor`

```
class GallerySelectState extends State<GallerySelect> {

  List<bool> isSelected = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isSelected = List<bool>.generate(widget.facegalleries.length, (i) {
      if (i == widget.currentFG) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
   /* .................. */

    child: ToggleButtons(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      children: <Widget>[
        for (var facegallery in widget.facegalleries) Text(
          facegallery,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF7A7F83),
            fontSize: 14,
          )
        )
      ],
      isSelected: isSelected,
      onPressed: (int index) {
        widget.onFGChange(index);
        setState(() {
          isSelected.replaceRange(0, isSelected.length, isSelected.map((element) => false));
          isSelected[index] = true;
          print(isSelected);
        });
      },
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      fillColor: Color(0xFF18C47B),
    )   
}
```

Comment: Have never used "ToggleButtons" but have had similar problems the state is a list. I am guessing that the widget only has a reference (a pointer) to the list and does not detect changes properly. You might be able to just use an empty setState to rebuild the entire widget. Otherwise, you could use keys to redraw parts of it.

Comment: I don't think reference is the problem here as documented here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html you can use initialized list as the value of `isSelected` property and the setState would still reflect the change yet somehow it doesn't here